# Putting an expiry on an alarm

Tags: java, date, alarmmanager, android-alarms

So I have alarms set in a database which my application takes from, however I want to be able to put an expiry date on these alarms (there for medication). How would I do this?

Here is my code for the alarms:

```
private void calMeds(int medication1, String time1) {

    String string = time1; 
    String[] parts = string.split(":");
    String part1 = parts[0]; 
    String part2 = parts[1]; 
    Log.e("DATABASE", "Hours: " + part1);
    Log.e("DATABASE", "Minutes: " + part2);

    hourCorrect = Integer.parseInt(part1);
    minuteCorrect = Integer.parseInt(part2);

    Date date = new Date();
    Calendar cal_Alarm = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar cal_Now = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal_Now.setTime(date);

    cal_Alarm.setTime(date);
    cal_Alarm.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourCorrect);
    cal_Alarm.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minuteCorrect);
    cal_Alarm.set(Calendar.SECOND, 3);

    if (cal_Alarm.before(cal_Now)) { 
        cal_Alarm.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);

    }

    alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    String ALARM_ACTION;
```

If I have an alarm going off everyday at 9:00 and its expiry date is the 21st of March, how do I stop it from alarming after this date? The times are entered in a database, and each have a different expiry date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your revision:

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar then = Calendar.getInstance();
    then.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
    then.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
    then.set(Calendar.HOUR, hour);
    then.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);

    long dif = then.getTimeInMillis() - now.getTimeInMillis();

    ActionListener action = new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(!alarm.isStopped())
            alarm.stop();
    }
    };

    Timer timer = new Timer((int)dif, action);
    timer.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use scheduler to schedule your alarm's expiry

Example:- (Suppose you want to exit your program after 30 minutes)

```
 java.util.Timer timer = new java.util.Timer();
  timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            System.exit(0);
                        }
                    }, 30 * 60 * 1000);
                }
```